# I don't receive contact invitations on Skype

Tags: windows-7, skype

I'm using Skype 6.0.0.126 on Windows 7 (64 bits) and this morning a friend of mine sent me an invitation to add her as a contact but I didn't received it, so I send her back an invitation. but again she had the same problem as I did. Any ideas of what's going on? (Sorry for my English)